# List of classes. c# search by type to find element x then search the items in the list around x to find the nearest element Y.

Tags: c#, list

I'm parsing a CSV document and taking in each line of input.

I have an object or a class with several values that are put into a list.

camobject.type is what we store either x or y into.

we search the list of objects for object.type == x then we need to search backwards for an object of type y.

any thoughts on how to search for y after we have found x?

Comment: You can use Regex.Matches https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx to get all matches in document and then by accessing their Index properties find the one you need

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with these techniques so here's a solution that might be not relevant, but some pseudo code to give you some idea's:

```
int found = 0;
int positionX = 0;
int positionY = 0;
for(int a = 0; a < list.Count && a >= 0; a++){
    if(list[a] == x && !found){
        positionX = a;
        found = 1;
        continue;
    }
    if(found){
        if(list[a] == y){
            positionY = a;
            break;
        }
        x -= 2; //from the moment x is found, go back one step at the time (search backwards)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ:

```
class Class5
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string file = @"YYY qqq                ccc              YYY                       ddd                      XXX  zzz YYY         zzz      ddd    YYY";            

        Match matchX = new Regex("XXX").Match(file);            

        MatchCollection collection = new Regex("YYY").Matches(file);
        Match[] matchesY = new Match[collection.Count];
        collection.CopyTo(matchesY, 0);

        int ClosestY = matchX.Index - matchesY.Where(m => matchX.Index > m.Index).Min(m => matchX.Index - m.Index);

        Console.WriteLine("Index of closest Y: {0}, Value: {1}", ClosestY, file.Substring(ClosestY, 3));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Or Without LINQ:

```
class Class5
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string file = @"YYY qqq                ccc              YYY                       ddd                      XXX  zzz YYY         zzz      ddd    YYY";            

        Match matchX = new Regex("XXX").Match(file);

        MatchCollection matchesY = new Regex("YYY").Matches(file);
        int minYIndex = -1;

        foreach (Match item in matchesY)
        {
            if (matchX.Index - item.Index > matchX.Index - minIndex || matchX.Index - item.Index < 0) continue;
            minYIndex = item.Index;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Index of closest Y: {0}, Value: {1}", minYIndex, file.Substring(minIndex, 3));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```